# Progress bar, wait form

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my main form, i have a button to load alot of stored process across multiple databases. I wanted to create a progress/waiting form while this loads. when i press the button i have it showdialog the waitform.
I have a backgroundworker process that calls workerDoWork.
Within that method i want to call the main form that has all the code to do the loading.  When i make it public i can call it. but theres so many references inside the main form, global variables, different methods being called it doesn't work.  How can i get it to work without having to move all the code into the wait form.?

Code inside the wait form.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)

    _worker = New BackgroundWorker()
    AddHandler _worker.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    AddHandler _worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted

    _worker.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

' This is executed on a worker thread and will not make the dialog unresponsive.  If you want
' to interact with the dialog (like changing a progress bar or label), you need to use the
' worker's ReportProgress() method (see documentation for details)
Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    'Dim main As New frmMain()
    frmMain.LoadARData()
    ' MsgBox("hi there ")

End Sub




' This is executed on the UI thread after the work is complete.  It's a good place to either
' close the dialog or indicate that the initialization is complete.  It's safe to work with
' controls from this event.
Private Sub WorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us your code or we can not help you!

Comment: In what way does it "not work?"

Comment: well i found that its weird.. if i run the methods off the main form , i pass in a date variable to my stored proc. dtpAgeDte.Text which is auto set upon load.  but if i call the method from the wait form.. it bombs and says cannot convert string "" to date.. its like its not picking up the date

Comment: If you do the processing with a BGWm why do you also need a Wait form?

Comment: i just have a form that shows "waiting" , a loading form to show the user it loading... thats the point

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
frmMain.LoadARData()
```

which is using the **default instance** of frmMain and most likely is not the same as the one you've got displayed on screen (causing the errors and unexpected behavior).

You need to reference the correct instance of frmMain for it to work correctly.  One way to solve this is to pass the reference to frmMain into the Show()/ShowDialog() call:

```
' ... running from within frmMain ...
Dim progress As New frmProgress()
progress.ShowDialog(Me) ' <-- passing in "Me" (the reference to frmMain)
```

Now, over in your progress form, you can cast the Owner property to the frmMain type and call your desired method:

```
Private Sub WorkerDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim main As frmMain = DirectCast(Me.Owner, frmMain)
    main.LoadARData()
End Sub
```

Comment: I've posted a tested anser here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769276/best-way-to-display-a-progress-form-while-a-method-is-executing-code/45406217#45406217